# Android Studio как изменить иконки папки и класса как было в старой студии?

Tags: android, android-studio, ui

Android Studio как изменить иконки папки и класса как было в старой студии?

в новой версии Android Studio иконки папка и класс стали синего цвета, отвлекает и мешает работать.

подскажите пожалуйста как убрать или поменять их как были в старой версии(зеленого цвета).

[image: UI]

Comment: Есть [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7285-idea-2016-2-icon-pack), который меняет на старые иконки IDEA. [Скриншот](http://www.screencast.com/t/nNjlyrLltqs). Этот плагин так же доступен в репозитории плагинов AS. А вообще придется смириться или писать свой плагин.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробывать

Comment: Плагин называется *Idea 2016.2 Icon Pack*, если вдруг ссылка сломается. Вообще этот плагин - обычный JAR, в котором иконки лежат в виде PNG-картинок. То есть, его можно скачать со страницы плагина, с минимальными усилиями подменить иконки на свои и установить модифицированный плагин в AS.